# Combining different tenses

Tags: tiempos-verbales

While speaking, are you allowed to combine tenses (and even moods)? In particular, I was learning about the conditional tenses and have learned that there are the simple, continuous and perfect conditional tenses. Could I combine the latter two to create a perfect continuous conditional tense? In English this would read as follows:

> If I had my phone, I would have been calling my boyfriend.

So in Spanish, would this be:

> Si tuviera mi teléfono, habría estado llamando a mi novio.

or is there a better way for this to be translated?

Comment: To my ears the sentence you want to translate sounds wrong and should start _If I had had_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Si tuviera mi teléfono, habría estado llamando a mi novio" o ¿Hay una mejor manera de traducir esto?

- "He estado llamando/llamándote" o "Te he estado llamando"(=I've been+ing+for+x time, without receiving an answer)
- "Si hubiera/hubiese tenido(participle past) mi/el X (at that time), podría haber llamado a mi Y" o "...podría haber(la/lo) llamado"[she couldn't do anything because..] (=if I had .. would've+p.p)
- "**De haberlo tenido**" o "Si hubiera/hubiese tenido mi/el X" (at that time), "(lo/la) habría/hubiera/hubiese podido llamar"(+inf)[he didn't, at that point, I had no choice...] (If you'd had ...I would/could/might've been able)
- "**Si tuviera**(subjunctive imperfect)/tuviese mi/el X (right now or at all times)" o "Si lo tuviera/tuviese, **ya (lo) estaría llamando** o "lo llamaría sin problema/siempre/lo pasaría llamando/llamándola/lo(= would spend time+ing)"[she does not lose hope if...] (If I had ... I would be+ing/I would've p.p)
- "De tener mi/el X" o "De tenerlo' (a while ago), ya (lo) habría/hubiese/hubiera llamado"[in response to a question] (If I had/were ... I would've p.p)
- "Si tengo(indicative present) mi/el X" o "Si lo tengo, (sí)(sin ninguna duda voy a llamarlo/la, de inmediato, al tiro)  lo/la llamo(indicative present)[we refer to the immediate future](as soon as possible)(if I simple p.v... I'll verb)(Tan pronto lo tenga(subjunctive present), en cuanto lo tenga (lo/la) llamo)

---

EDIT: "Habría estado llamando" is not idiomatic, or at least not to my ears. This is how I would say it:

- **Si tuviera** mi móvil "ya lo **estaría** llamando" o "ya estaría llamando"(if p.t...I'd be+ing)
- Si **tuviera** mi móvil ya lo **habría/hubiera/hubiese llamado**(...would've already+p.p)
- Ya **estaría llamando** de tener mi móvil a mano.
- Si **hubiera tenido** mi móvil, **ya me habría podido** comunicar con él.
- **De haber tenido** el móvil a mano, **no hubiera parado** de hacerle llamadas(if I did, I wouldn't have had)
- **Hubiera/habría estado pegada** al móvil **intentando** hacerle llamadas, pero como no lo tenía/tuve, no pudo ser.
- **Como no tenía** el móvil, no pude hacer ni una sola llamada(Since I didn't have ....could not.../but was unable due...)

---

EDIT2:

- **Estuve llamando** pero me salía que estaba ocupado(I tried calling him, but.., I've been calling but...)
- **Me había estado llamando** mucho, pero se me quedó el móvil, no pude contestarle(He had been calling me but...)

In another context, an example of the opposite is she continuously receiving a ton of missed calls from him, so I wouldn't put it that way. I would not use "habría" in my Spanish for meaning "había" or "habrá".

The **past perfect continuous tense**(«Haber conjugated + the past participle of Estar + gerund») is used to describe actions that began in the past and often continued for a short period of time after the action started, BUT instead, in the case given as an example in the question, she **was not able to make any phone calls**.

Therefore, I could imagine myself using either the **conditional perfect** **to talk about something that would've happened but didn’t due to another action**:

- "Si tuviera mi móvil,...**habría llamado**".

or **the Continuous Conditional** translated as “Would Be Doing” in **hypothetical conditional** paired with the **imperfect subjunctive**:

- "Si tuviera mi móvil,...**ya estaría llamando**"(if p.t ...I'd be+ing)

or the **Pluperfect subjunctive** that **is used to express subjectivity in the past**, which is formed with the imperfect subjunctive of the auxiliary verb haber + the past participle of the main.

- De **haber**lo **tenido**, **lo hubiera/habría hecho**..(if I did/, I wouldn't have had..| would have done this....if x had had) (*Si hubiera tenido mi móvil, ya me habría podido comunicar con él.*)

Comment: Están un poco confusas las explicaciones, tal vez se podría usar __italicas para las explicaciones en inglés__ , **negritas para textos en castellano** y __subrayado__ en las partes adecua__das__ para resaltar las declinaciones

Comment: Haha en comentarios no funciona el markdown

Comment: Sorry, I am finding this difficult to understand. Could you please expand on your answer to my question more directly please?

Comment: @user33120 "Habría estado llamando" is not idiomatic, or at least not to my ears. The past continuous tense is used to describe actions that began in the past and often continued for a short period of time after the action started, but instead, she was not able to make any phone calls. I'd use either the conditional perfect to talk about something that would've happened but didn’t due to another action "habría llamado"(...would've called)(p.p)) or "ya estaría llamando"(if p.t ...I'd be+ing) or de haberlo tenido, no hubiera..(if I did, I wouldn't have had)